# Fade Background but NOT Text

Tags: html, css, fade

I have applied a CSS fade in/out solution to a div, which im happy with, for the most part.
However I only want to apply it to the background, not the text. I need the text to be fully opaque at all times.

See example:
http://jsfiddle.net/howiepaul/gUAPV/33/

```
a.tab {background-color:#d4d4d4;
font-family: arial;
font-weight: bold;}

a.tab:hover {
opacity:1;
animation: tickhov 1.5s;
-moz-animation: tickhov 1.5s; /* Firefox */
-webkit-animation: tickhov 1.5s; /* Safari and Chrome */}
@-ms-keyframes tickhov {from {opacity:0.2;} to {opacity:1;}}
@-moz-keyframes tickhov /* Firefox */ {from {opacity:0.2;} to {opacity:1;}}
@-webkit-keyframes tickhov /* Safari and Chrome */ {from {opacity:0.2;} to {opacity:1;}}

a.tab{
opacity:0.2;
animation: letgo 1.5s;
-moz-animation: letgo 1.5s; /* Firefox */
-webkit-animation: letgo 1.5s; /* Safari and Chrome */}
@-ms-keyframes letgo {from {opacity:1;} to {opacity:0.2; visibility: hidden; display: none;}}
@-moz-keyframes letgo /* Firefox */ {from {opacity:1;} to {opacity:0.2; visibility: hidden; display: none;}}
@-webkit-keyframes letgo /* Safari and Chrome */ {from {opacity:1;} to {opacity:0.2; visibility: hidden; display: none;}}
```

Any help would be gratefully received.

Many thanks
Howie

Comment: You could use CSS transitions to do it: http://jsfiddle.net/gUAPV/36/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be animating on `background-color` not `opacity`. FYI if this is all you're doing you should use transitions instead of animations, they're much simpler.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Tyriar/zrMTd/2/)

```
a.tab {
    position:relative;
    font-family: arial;
    font-weight: bold;
    background-color:rgba(212,212,212,.2);
    -moz-transition:background-color 1.5s ease;
    -webkit-transition:background-color 1.5s ease;
    transition:background-color 1.5s ease;
}

a.tab:hover {
    background-color:rgba(212,212,212,1);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Daniel, I think this is the option to go for!

Answer (score 1):

No need to use animations for this and write such a bulky code. If you just need to change the  background keeping the text as it is, you should use **CSS Transitions** instead. They are much simpler and easy to use and this can be achieved with very few lines of code. Here is the fiddle demo

http://jsfiddle.net/gUAPV/37/

```
a.tab {
    background-color: #f4f4f4; 
    font-family: arial;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size : 40px;
}

a.tab:hover {
   background-color:#d4d4d4;

   -webkit-transition: background 300ms ease-in 200ms;
   -moz-transition: background 300ms ease-in 200ms;
   -o-transition: background 300ms ease-in 200ms;
   transition: background 300ms ease-in 200ms;
}
```

I have increased the Font size to make it more prominent to see, you can adjust according to your use.

P.S. If you want to read some more about CSS Transitions here are some useful links

[W3.Org Link](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-transitions/)

[Mozilla Develper Forum Link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Tutorials/Using_CSS_transitions)

Hope this helps :)